# Finding duplicate records in a specific date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I have 4 columns 
**Serial(nvarchar), SID(nvarchar), DateCreated(Date), CID(unique and int)**
I want to find the records where there is duplicate **serial** and **SID** and where the 2 duplicate **serial** fall between date range of 180 days.

please help

Sample Data

```
Serial          SID     DateCreated             CID 
02302-25-0036   HONMD01 2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 1
02302-25-0036   HONMD01 2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 3
0264607         HONMD01 2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 65
0264607         HONMD01 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 45
03118-09-0366   PRIVA00 2016-05-20 00:00:00.000 34
03118-09-0366   PRIVA00 2016-05-20 00:00:00.000 87
0969130         140439  2017-05-09 00:00:00.000 32
0969130         140439  2017-05-09 00:00:00.000 23
1049567         INIIL00 2017-04-12 00:00:00.000 76
```

Comment: Please provide us some sample data and expected output

Comment: Do you want to understand if the current line was in the last 180 days?

Comment: Added sample data.
For example for serial 02302-25-0036 there are two entries with same SID and both fall within 180 days we want that data. if two dates are more than 180 apart we don't want that

Comment: Don't add sample data as image. Its difficult to copy-paste it

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #Test (Serial nvarchar(20), [SID] nvarchar(10), DateCreated datetime, CID int)

Insert into #Test   values ('02302-25-0036', 'HONMD01', '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 1)
                    , ('02302-25-0036', 'HONMD01', '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 3)
                    , ('0264607', 'HONMD01', '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 65)
                    , ('0264607', 'HONMD01', '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000', 45)
                    , ('03118-09-0366', 'PRIVA00', '2016-05-20 00:00:00.000', 34)
                    , ('03118-09-0366', 'PRIVA00', '2016-05-20 00:00:00.000', 87)
                    , ('0969130', '140439', '2017-05-09 00:00:00.000', 32)
                    , ('0969130', '140439', '2017-05-09 00:00:00.000', 23)
                    , ('1049567', 'INIIL00', '2017-04-12 00:00:00.000', 76)

select distinct a.* 
from
(
select t.*
from #Test t
inner join (
    Select Serial, [SID]
    from #Test
    group by Serial, [SID]
    Having count(*)>=2
    ) d on d.Serial = t.Serial and t.SID= t.SID
) a
full outer join
(
select t.*
from #Test t
inner join (
    Select Serial, [SID]
    from #Test
    group by Serial, [SID]
    Having count(*)>=2
    ) d on d.Serial = t.Serial and t.SID= t.SID
) b on a.Serial = b.Serial and a.SID= b.SID
where datediff(d,a.DateCreated, b.DateCreated)<180
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        serial,
        sid,
        dateCreated,
        cid,
        coalesce(max(dateCreated) over(partition by serial, sid order by cid, dateCreated asc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), '1900-01-01') as last,
        coalesce(min(dateCreated) over(partition by serial, sid order by cid, dateCreated asc rows between 1 following and unbounded following), '5999-01-01') as next
    from table_name
) 
select *
from cte 
where 
    datediff(day, last, dateCreated) >= 180
    and datediff(day, dateCreated, next) >= 180
```

Comment: Thank you Евгений Кондратенко

Answer (score 0):

This was a challenging question ! I have left final output with *(PreviousDate, rno) for easy understanding. Here is my way to solve :

```
Create table #t(Serial nvarchar(100),SID nvarchar(100),DateCreated date,CID int)
Insert into #t values 
('02302-25-0036',   'HONMD01', '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 1),
('02302-25-0036',   'HONMD01', '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 3),
('0264607',         'HONMD01', '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 65),
('0264607',         'HONMD01', '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000', 45),
('03118-09-0366',   'PRIVA00', '2016-05-20 00:00:00.000', 34),
('03118-09-0366',   'PRIVA00', '2016-05-20 00:00:00.000', 87),
('0969130',         '140439',  '2017-05-09 00:00:00.000', 32),
('0969130',         '140439',  '2017-05-09 00:00:00.000', 23),
('1049567',         'INIIL00', '2017-04-12 00:00:00.000', 76)

Select iq2.*
FROM
 (Select iq.Serial, iq.SID, iq.DateCreated, iq.CID, iq.PreviousDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY iq.Serial,iq.SID, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, iq.DateCreated, iq.PreviousDate) <= 180 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                            ORDER BY Serial,SID) rno
  FROM
      (select Serial,SID,DateCreated,CID,
              MAX(DateCreated) OVER (PARTITION BY Serial,SID ORDER BY Serial,SID) maxDate,
              DATEADD(day,-180,MAX(DateCreated) OVER (PARTITION BY Serial,SID ORDER BY Serial,SID)) PreviousDate
       from #t
    )iq
 )iq2 
where iq2.rno <> 1
```

output :

```
Serial                    SID        DateCreated   CID         PreviousDate   rno
----------               -------     ----------   ----         -----------   ----
02302-25-0036            HONMD01     2017-05-01    3           2016-11-02     2
03118-09-0366            PRIVA00     2016-05-20    87          2015-11-22     2
0969130                  140439      2017-05-09    23          2016-11-10     2
```

PS : PreviousDate is MAX PreviousDate